# how to store String values in array using scanner

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I want to input studentId and studentName using Scanner and store these values to a array/s.

```
System.out.print("Enter StudentId :");
String studentId = input.nextLine();

System.out.print("Enter StudentName :");
String studentName = input.nextLine();
```

Can I store these values(not a single value) to a array?

Comment: You mean `String[] myArray = { studentId, studentName }` ? Or else what do you mean?

Comment: I mean i want to use Scanner to store values to this `String[] myArray = { studentId, studentName }` array.

Comment: you can use loop for arrays, or taking whole line as one input and use split()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
// short version
String[] myArray = new String[]{
        studentId,
        studentName
};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));

// adding one by one
String[] myArray1 = new String[2];
myArray1[0] = studentId;
myArray1[1] = studentName;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray1));
```

Answer (score 1):

taking whole line as one input and splitting them. If input is seperated by comma, use `split(",")` or if seperated by space, use `split(" ")`

```
String input = sc.nextLine();
String[] myArray = input.split(" ");
```

```
input : 
R123 Ravi 

myArray will become {"R123","Ravi"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using BufferedReader

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("Enter StudentID,StudentName");
String[] arr = br.readLine.trim().split(",");
```

Keep in mind

1. While inputs provide studentid and studentname as comma separated (you can change it if you want as per you requirement).
2. You need to import java.io.*;
3. This throws exception. So you can either add throws IO Exception with your main method or put all this in try catch.

Input

```
101, Virat
```